Need help understanding 'vector larger than max_size() with my program.' + how to fix it
so with this c++ program, I'm using zybooks to run this program, and this is the first time I've seen this error before, but it just gives me : vector larger than max_size(), larger than max_size() or nothing at all, like usually it'll say "program produced no output" but not even that is produced. I just need help understanding what the heck that error is and how I could rectify this issue. Thank you for reading.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int numElements;
   int lowerBound;
   int upperBound;
   
   cin >> numElements;

   vector<int> numInts(numElements);
   for(int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i) {
      cin >> numInts.at(i);
      }
   cin >> lowerBound;
   cin >> upperBound;
   
   for(int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i) {
      if(numInts.at(i) >= lowerBound && numInts.at(i) <= upperBound) {
         cout << numInts.at(i) + ",";
      }
   }
   
   cout << endl;

   return 0;
}


Given that it said something about my vector being larger than max_size(), I tried editing the i < numElements to i < numElements - 1 and that just produces no output, I've also used the size() method to no avail, and just changing numElements to no avail as well. Please excuse my inexperience, I'm yet to finish my semester of c++ programming I.

All vectors have a maximum size, which typically depends on the system the program is running on (like for example available memory). If you try to create a vector bigger than this maximum size (i.e. numElements is larger than the maximum size) then an exception will be thrown.

Maybe cin >> numElements; failed because you typed a word instead of a number. Or maybe you typed a number larger than 2,147,483,647. Your code has no error handling for user input and you also don't initialize your variables.

The input is verified as a integer, it is 5. i think i narrowed it down to the issue being in the first for loop, as it gives out an error of "25 51 0 200 33 ector larger than max_size()," which allows me to type in some of the input, but then fails after the loop.

The bug is numInts.at(i) + "," it should be numInts.at(i)  << "," The + attempts to output the numInts.at(i)'th element of the "," array which has 1 element + null terminator: https://ideone.com/XvQrZH

dude thank you so much . i did not see that at all.

Be careful to avoid using +  with string literals.

Why all those calls to at()? You know that i is a valid index because you wrote it that way. There’s no need to waste time checking it, especially in that second loop, which checks the same index value three times. Just use numInts[i].

Also, nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that ’std::endldoes. Use'\n'` to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

"Given that it said something about my vector being larger than max_size()" you should have read, and reported here, the exact error message. Not a summary, a paraphrase, a precis, what you thought it said, or "something about".

@user207421 I was able to reproduce the error but I have never seen it before as I mostly use msvc. If you just run this (not debug) on onlinegdb: https://onlinegdb.com/VeaI81KJB it prints the following error at the end:  :vector larger than max_size()ze()larger than max_size()

As mentioned by drescherjm the bug is in the last for loop:
cout << numInts.at(i) + ",";

You're adding a string literal to an int.
What you want to do is:
cout << numInts.at(i) << ",";

The best way to avoid this kind of mistake is by using a compiler with warnings on.
I wrote a short code review, providing ressources, and rewrote the code.
Live on compiler explorer
Hopefully it will inspire you to learn more about the language!
